# IOS - Programatically add additional UI elements to TableView Prototype Cell

Tags: ios, storyboard, prototype, tableview

I have made a simple prototype cell with a button and a label in Storyboard builder in Xcode, using the Master Detail template (iPhone). Now I need to know how to add additional labels or other UI elements in the cell programmatically. Please advise... Thanks.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    TSTest *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell2" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDate *object = _objects[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel1.text = [object description];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: You can add any number of subviews to content view of the cell using [cell.contentView addSubview:myLabel];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is why you want to do that. You can do it, but consider why first. Is it better to create different prototype cells for different purposes, then you can choose at runtime which to use and the layout of all of the cells is set in the same place (storyboard).

That said, when you dequeue a cell you can add any subviews you want to it. How you deal with the position of the old and new subviews depends on if you have auto-layout turned on. You should also check, each time you dequeue a cell whether it has subviews that you previously added (and then reuse them or remove them).

Comment: Yup, simply create different prototype cells.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do it is to create everything programmatically. But here is how in your case.

```
static NSString *TableViewCellIdentifier = @"Cell2";
if (myCustomCellView == nil){
            myCustomCellView = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                          initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                          reuseIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];    
    //Creating my custom lable - myLable

    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 100, 25.0);
    myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    myLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [myCellView.contentView addSubview:myLabel];
}
SomeDictionary *someDictionaryOrWhatEver = [[SomeDictionary alloc] init];
someDictionaryOrWhatEver = [self.someKindOfList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@" , someDictionaryOrWhatEver.someKeyValue;
```

Hope that helps.

For more please visit the following links:
http://jslim.net/blog/2013/03/22/ios-create-uitableview-with-custom-cell-programmatically/
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-crafting-custom-uitableview-cells--mobile-15702
Cheers

Comment: You should never, ever, do anything programmatically on iOS.  You must always use storyboard.